# В предложении правильно будет написать "которые" или "который"?

Tags: синтаксис, выбор-слов

Любовь — один из самых высоких поступков, на *которые* способен человек.

Answer (score 1):

Если ничего по смыслу не менять, то правильно так:
*Любовь — один из самых высоких поступков, **на которые** способен человек.*

Союзное слово "которые" связывает с главным предложением придаточное, определяющее существительное "поступки" главного предложения.

> Простите, Алексей Федорович, я не могу вспомнить без негодования этого позорного его поступка... одного из таких поступков, **на которые** может решиться только один Дмитрий Федорович в своем гневе... и в страстях своих!
> Ф. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы

Мне кажется, что про [любовь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C) все-таки правильно писать "чувство".
Человек способен на многие чувства, любовь — одно из них.

*Любовь... Пожалуй, это самое прекрасное из всех **чувств**, на которые способен человек* ([ЕГЭ. Литература. Сборник...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=1r9EEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=%22%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%22&source=bl&ots=AY70d4XqtD&sig=ACfU3U10tdVT9GLgK9XtDQ7jKca6ZGKJOA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4osaD7sT6AhUJqIsKHUXKBt04KBDoAXoECBEQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%22&f=false)).